# How to setup virtual host using Wamp Server properly?

Tags: php, apache, wampserver

I need your help here in creating a virtual host in wampserver. In office I can create a virtual hosts but when I try to create in my laptop it doesn't work. I still can't figure out what's wrong. Here's what I did.

1. I copy the wordpress file in this folder. This will be the path of my project

   - E:\Subversion\chelle.wpblog.local
2. I edit the host file

   - C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
   - I added it to the end of file

     127.0.0.1   chelle.wpblog.local
3. Next is I enable the virtual host in Apache

   - C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\conf\httpd.conf
   - I uncomment this

     Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
4. Next is I setup the virtual host in WAMP

   - C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf
   - I add this at the bottom

     ```
     <VirtualHost *:80>
         ServerName chelle.wpblog.local
         ServerAlias chelle.wpblog.local
         DocumentRoot "E:/Subversion/chelle.wpblog.local/"
         <Directory "E:/Subversion/chelle.wpblog.local/">
             Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
             AllowOverride All
             Order allow,deny
             allow from all    
         </Directory>
     </VirtualHost>
     ```
5. Last is restart wampserver and open the chelle.wpblog.local in the browser. And it doesn't display. It display only google search results.

Comment: You asked a question about an hour ago, but deleted it since. If still looking for an answer, I assume [this](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/ugum52kr/) might help.

Answer (score 27):

I was installing the zend framework on my local wamp using apache server.
First go and decide what will be your domain name for the local url.
**Ex->www.test_zend_tutorial.com**
then go and open the file located at **"C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc"**

> hosts

write

> 127.0.0.1 (use one tab space) **www.test_zend_tutorial.com**

then go to the folder located at

> D:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.17 (whatever is your version) \conf\

and open the file

> httpd.conf

and search for text

> **Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf**

and **uncomment it by removing the # tag from the start of the line**.Save the file and close it.
Now go to another folder located at

> D:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.17\conf\extra

and open the file

> httpd-vhosts.conf

and paste the code below at the last in this file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "D:\wamp\www"
    ServerName localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/localhost-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.test_zend_tutorial.com
   DocumentRoot "D:\wamp\www\(your project folder name)\public"
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <directory "D:\wamp\www\(your project folder name)\public">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride all
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and restart the wamp, now write the **www.test_zend_tutorial.com** in the browser and you will see the things working.

Answer (score 10):

If when you use the new domain in the browser it goes to a google search or something like that then the change to your hosts file has not been recognised.

You have to either reboot after changing the hosts file or more simply run these 2 commands from a command windows ( as administrator )

```
net stop dnscache
net start dnscache
```

This will refresh windows DNS cache and pick up your hosts file changes.

It is also a good idea to `ping` your new domain to check it is being seen, use

```
ping chelle.wpblog.local
```

If it reports 127.0.0.1 as the ip address and 4 send and 4 receieved packet then the domain is now known to Windows, if it reports some other ip address the hosts file change has not succeeded.

Also it is a good idea when creating VHOSTS to also create one for localhost or the wamp home page will not work.
You also have old Apache 2.2 syntax (Order allow,deny allow from all) you could try using the Apache 2.4 syntax, see below

So try this

```
## must be first so the the wamp menu page loads
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mail.net
    DocumentRoot "D:/wamp/www"
    ServerName localhost
    <Directory  "D:/wamp/www">
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mail.net
    ServerName chelle.wpblog.local 
    ServerAlias www.chelle.wpblog.local 
    DocumentRoot "E:/Subversion/chelle.wpblog.local" 
    <Directory "E:/Subversion/chelle.wpblog.local"> 
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews 
        AllowOverride All 
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 4):

In WampServer 3.0.4 you do not need to run through all those setting up.
Go to local host and under Tools area for "Add a Vertual Host" in the first time it will say turn on "Vertual Host sub menu" in wamp server settings. 
To get there right click on wamp icon > go to wamp server settings > and click on Vertual Host sub menu. Then re-fresh the page and follow the setup process, you just need to provide the server name and path. It will do all the works for you. 
Simple as that

Answer (score 4):

**Method 1:**

in hosts file

```
127.0.0.1   mysite
::1 mysite
```

in C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.23\conf\extra\httpd-vosts.conf file add your virtual host as follows

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysite
    DocumentRoot "<path_to_your_local_site>"
    <Directory  "<path_to_your_local_site>">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Make sure vhost configuration is enable in httpd.conf file is enabled as follows
C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.23\conf\httpd.conf

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

After you have changed configuration as above, restart all service in wamp and load website as follows
http://mysite
your local site should open.

**Method 2:**

In latest versions of wamp, you can do this configuration via webpage.
Open localhost in your browser. You would see wamp welcome page.

Down below under Tools, there is option to add virtual host. click on the link which would take you to add virtual host page.

In Name of the host, enter your site name eg: mysite
Under Complete absolute path of the VirtualHost folder, enter the path of your site.

Save the config and restart all services. you should be able to open mysite with the link http://mysite

As pointed in another answer, in newer versions of wam

Comment: 2nd method is very easy to add VH through UI. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

The answers above are overcomplicating the problem somewhat, and in fact the question is including extra information that's misleading the responders.

The clues lie in step 2 and the symptoms described in 5. The hosts file is set up but when the request is made to "blah.local", google responds. Apache is not involved.

The first step to diagnosis would be pinging blah.local and seeing that it maps correctly to 127.0.0.1. I have never (in many years as a developer) found it necessary to restart local DNS on either Windows or Linux/Mac so I would expect this to work out of the box. But if it doesn't, of course restart DNS and see that it does.

However, late versions of Chrome at least do not recognize the TLD '.local' and so when you put the URL back in the browser, it's passed on to Google as a search term. There may be a setting in your browser to tell it to handle the unsanctioned TLD, but your simplest solution would be to use a TLD that's sanctioned by W3C like '.com'.

In short, if your hosts file reads something like

```
127.0.0.1     local.chelle.wpblog.com
```

rather than

```
127.0.0.1     chelle.wpblog.local
```

everything should work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the folder for your local website
2. Go to localhost (browser)
3. Click Add a Virtual Host button
4. Add the name of the virtual host
5. Add the complete absolute path
6. Restart DNS