# Configure Laravel routing on a WAMP Server

Tags: php, laravel, mod-rewrite, routes

I'm learning Laravel framework, but I have a weird problem in the routing. For example when I access *localhost/iMall* it will only show list of files and folders, i should explicitly access *localhost/iMall/public* and when I access 
localhost/public/index.php it will got to localhost/index.php showing the index page of WAMP server. And adding any routes is not working for example:
in app/http/routes.php i wrote this:

```
<?php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('hi', function () {
    return view('Hi'); // Hi.blade.php
});
```

But this is not working, the mod_rewrite is enabled and AllowOverride is set to all. I'm using WAMP 3.0.4 
Any help?

Comment: What version of Laravel do you use?

Comment: @Webdesigner Exactly: 5.4.36, however i will try your answer, hope it works. Thank you anyway

Comment: wow! no, i was following a tutorial, maybe i missed the version they used. i will try that

Comment: Thank you, this worked! however it still when i access iMall/hi it show nothing i should access iMall/public/hi to reach the hi view!

Comment: The fact its on a WAMPServer in not relevant here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In laravel 5.4 you should put your route in `/routes/web.php` and not `/app/http/routes.php`

You should als change you Virtual Host configuration on your WAMP Server.

Laravel expects that your Document Root is /public so if you enter localhost is should point to `/path/to/laravel_project/public`

Now the default in WAMP is that he shows you the WAMP index.php.

Now what you can do it to add a new domain in you hosts file.
`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` and add the flowing line at the end:
`127.0.0.1   laravel.dev`

Now in you have to add a [new Virtual Host on your WAMP Server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25203499/5427950):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName laravel.dev
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp64/www/laravel_project/public"

    <Directory "C:/wamp64/www/laravel_project/public/">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and restart you WAMP Server

Now if you enter laravel.dev it should show you the `/` route of your Laravel Project.