# Localhost's Your Project isn't opening?

Tags: php, localhost, wamp, wampserver

when i click on any of the project listed in the localhost it wont open up, it only shows the url of the project like   **wp_brochure_site/**    this one but if i add localhost before that url like  **localhost/wp_brochure_site/**  it works out very well. Can anyone help me, im new to wamp server.
Thanks in Advance...

[Entering localhost any clicking on any projects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnYwy.png)

[image: image part 1 see the url]

After typing localhost in the url:
[image: Image part 2 see the url after typing localhost in the url]

using in window 10 operating sys.

Wampserver 3.1.0 64 bit x64 – Apache 2.4.27 – PHP 5.6.31, 7.0.23, 7.1.9 – MySQL 5.7.19 – MariaDB 10.2.8 – PhpMyAdmin 4.7.4 – Adminer 4.3.1 – PhpSysInfo 3.2.7

Comment: Did you create a Virtual Hosts? If you did did you add a reference to the VH in your HOSTS file

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no any [virtualhost](/questions/tagged/virtualhost) on the Apache server named `wp_brochure_site`. All your applications are found on the main host `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.

If you would like to access `http://wp_brochure_site` you have to do two things:

1. Create virtual host with this name.
2. Add a record in the [hosts](/questions/tagged/hosts)
   file that points `wp_brochure_site` to `127.0.0.1`

Checkout [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22217386/how-to-setup-virtual-host-using-wamp-server-properly) for more help.

Comment: as creating a point "127.0.0.1 wp_brochure_site" inside C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts isnt good ideea! you shoul use yes localhost/ wp_brochure_site or 127.0.0.1/wp_brochure_site istread to edit that file how other do wrong as well !

Comment: Yes but with creation of the virtual host.

Comment: sorry sir i didn't understand..actually i want the projects to open normally like localhost/wp_brochure_site but when i click on any of the projects it just throw the url of the project like wp_brochure_site/, i want it to open it like localhost/wp_brochure_site/    ,thanks in advance

Comment: yes but in some cases you can get security issues !  doing that edit on hosts will work well but will be an exploit and a security issue! that's the point!

Comment: @darsheelrathore it is better and worth to deal with each project as separate virtual host. However, if still you want that, you may edit the listing links of your projects.

Comment: @darsheelrathore If you worry about accessing your virtual hosts from other computers on the LAN or even outside it, you may checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22805501/1592845)

Comment: @Constantin Its not a bad idea! You can still keep your AV or Windows security on the HOSTS file, just allow yourself access while you amend it and then replace the security!!

Comment: well ther are manny websites are provide web servers solutions (manny are windows based) but ,not surely if is true , all i know /all i sow is only APACHEFRIENDS.ORG are completely sincere and they said the truth: you should use xampp for developing reason only and not in production. sharing your ip is insecure. i don't remember were they said ,i am very agree with that!  also sharing in network in hosts file a local ip that haven't network limitation on the output(firewal,...bla bla) will expose that ip to hackers's scanners=and you should avoid that !!! ..and many others reasons

Comment: @ RiggsFolly you can read int the preview message ..i forgot to add your nickname