# I can't show a file from storage in Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, laravel-filesystem, laravel-storage

I have a Laravel 6.0 application where users can upload files to a server and it stores in the storage file system of `laravel`. The system I'm using has been working in an older Laravel 5.6 project.

The link the Controller gives me:

> domainame.com/public/file?folder=foldername&file=1569323440filename.png

**Controller**

```php
public function getFile($foldername, $filename)
{
    $fullpath = "app/{$foldername}/{$filename}";

    return response()->download(storage_path($fullpath), null, [], null);
}

public function getFilesubfolder($foldername, $subfolder, $filename)
{
    $fullpath = "app/{$foldername}/{$subfolder}/{$filename}";

    return response()->download(storage_path($fullpath), null, [], null);
}
```

**View**

```php
{{ route('file.show' ,['folder' => 'empresas' , 'file' => $factura->archivo])}}
```

The error I get is a 404 error because the link is trying to access doesn't exist. In my previous project the link was something like this:

> domainame.com/public/folder/file

I created a symlink to the storage system. Am I missing another type of configuration or something?

Comment: your `domainame.com` vhost should have root in `/public` of your laravel project. The project urls should not start with a `/public`

Comment: @N69S I know, I edited the entire URL because it had my server ip address on it :)

Comment: take a look at this and setup a vhost correctly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22217386/how-to-setup-virtual-host-using-wamp-server-properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my error, want to post the solution here if people come from a google search or something else:

My error was that starting in Laravel 6.0, the variables routes MUST be literal.

In my case I changed this:

```
{{ route('file.show' ,['folder' => 'empresas' , 'file' => $factura->archivo])}}
```

To this:

```
{{ route('file.show' ,['foldername' => 'empresas' , 'filename' => $factura->archivo])}}
```

I broke my mind because I was not seeing that error, hope it helps to anyone that is in my situation