# After Deployment, Images not showing in Laravel

Tags: laravel, image, deployment, http-status-code-404

I created Common Helper for Image Upload & Common Trait Function for get Images Full URL from Storage & I tested it in Laravel's default inbuilt server it's 1005 perfectly works.

but after Deployment I can't Display Images. it's show **404 error** to me

I shared my Common function of Get Full URL path of Image from storage.

> app/Traits>HasProfilePhoto.php file

```
public function getProfilePhotoUrlAttribute()
{
    return $this->profile_photo_path
                ? Storage::disk($this->profilePhotoDisk())->url($this->profile_photo_path)
                : \URL::to('/').'/adminLTE/dist/img/user-img.png';
}
```

above function will returns Image's Full URL Path Like.**"test.com/storage/users/user.png"**

using Laravel's Default Inbuilt server it returns Full URL like this. **http://localhost:8000/storage/users/user.png**  & using that path **image display perfectly**

but after the **deployment in local Windows using XAMPP Server**, it returns Full URL like this. **http://localhost/ProjectFolderName/storage/users/user.png** & it's **show 404 Not Found**

> NOTE:- If I use FULL Url like this:- http://localhost/ProjectFolderName/public/storage/users/user.png then image displayed

**Please Help me what's my mistake there?**

*
**How I deployed my Laravel Project see below:- **

*

> root/server.php file renamed with index.php
>
> & root/public/.htaccess file copied at root directory

Comment: Your laravel public dir should be the domains root dir. Side note: XAMPP might not be the best option for a Laravel dev env (it's better to use `php artisan serve` for example )

Comment: @GertB. please can you share full detail example about deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename the `server.php` file to `index.php` is not good practice for security reasons as well. So if you need to hide the `public` path from the URL then create a `.htaccess` at root level:

```
<ifmodule mod_rewrite.c>

    <ifmodule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </ifmodule>
 
    RewriteEngine On
 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ server.php

</ifmodule>
```

**Updated by Harsh Patel:- 8th September 2021**

**Actually Problem is about defining Virtual Host in Server...** I was defined `DocumentRoot` path & `Directory` path as like `"C:/xampp/htdocs/projectFolderName/` this.

> I was identified my mistake in deployment from [here **medium's Blog**](https://insidert.medium.com/setting-up-laravel-project-on-windows-2aa7e4f080da)

but as per [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/deployment#server-configuration) **, we need to direct all requests to `public/index.php`** in other words Laravel's Public Folder is an Our Server's Root (public_html) folder that's why I need to define `DocumentRoot` & `Directory` up to public folder like this `C:/xampp/htdocs/projectFolderName/public`

- We need to define our Laravel Web in Apache Server's Virtual Host Config.

**for XAMPP Server**

step 1: open `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra` path location in XAMPP Server

step 2: Open **`httpd-vhosts.conf` File**

step 3: define virtual host rule as like below

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com
  DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/projectFolderName/public"
  <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/projectFolderName/public">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

IF you faced any problem to define **Virtual Host in XAMPP** then you can see Full detailed answer about **[How to define Virtual Host in XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36572751/14344959)**

& **If you Use WAMPP Server** then you can see Full detailed answers about **[How to define Virtual Host in WAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25203499/14344959)**

Comment: I already created symbolic of storage path at public path using command. & Storage::disk('public)->get('file.png') is get file or Image from blade template Or respond it in API but I want to pass Full Image Path which is located at storage. then using that path browser will get image automatically

Comment: no I can't access using Image using Manually in Browser. it's display 404 not found. & brother I deploy Laravel web in Our Server PC (OS:- Windows) locally. If I use laravel's default server then I can access manually also

Comment: function returns that path http://localhost/microtechcoupon/storage/users/user16148609746040d2ae9dd81.png but its show 404 error even I can't access manually in browser using this link.... But But When I try to http://localhost/microtechcoupon/public/storage/users/user16148609746040d2ae9dd81.png this link manually in browser then its works... So I think there was I made any mistake in deployment... otherwise function works properly

Comment: yes correct. but as I know we can access storage file directly without mention public before the storage URL & it works in default server, not works in deployment

Comment: can you tell me full details about how to deploy in Linux personal host, Linux Shared host & as well as how to deploy in local using xampp server???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236843/discussion-between-harsh-patel-and-amit-senjaliya).

Comment: yes I know, we can't interact direct without symbolic. that I already done. my meaning was without mention public in url

Comment: & asset() helper returns path upto public folder. & my function also returns full path. but its not work

Comment: Brother I have edited your answer. You can see exact solution of my question & I also accept your answer ... Thank you for your valuable time

Comment: @HarshPatel I have seen the edited answers. But when u set public folder root then no need to rename server.php to index

Comment: yes Exactly if we define public folder as a root directory then we did't need to rename server.php with index.php & as well as we didn't need to copy public/.htaccess file at root directory

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you just need to set your projects URL inside .env to start with http://

> APP_URL=http://your-project-url

Without this, images will not have proper URL but when you copy image path and open it inside new tab, image will be available anyway.

Comment: No, your opinion is correct but I was set APP_URL properly in .env configuration file. there is no issue in my case. I already edited answer of my problem in Amit Senjaliya's answer,. I have already solved my problem. Thanks

Comment: It's nice to hear that, in case someone else has a similar problem, it may help, since I've been looking for a solution for a while. You are welcome